# Postgresql Посчитать уникальные текстовые значения в столбце нарастающим итогом (по месяцам)

Tags: postgresql

Не могу сообразить, как посчитать нарастающим итогом количество уникальных id по месяцам (январь, январь+февраль, январь+февраль+март и т.д.). Использую код ниже, но он задваивает уникальные значения за январь+февраль, январь+февраль+март.

```
select 
    date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month,
    sum(count(distinct id)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created_at)) as cum_sum
from table
group by 1
```

На выходе хочется видеть таблицу:

```
месяц    количество_id
январь    91
февраль   166
март      205
```

Но я получаю такой результат:

```
месяц    количество_id
январь    91
февраль   257
март      462
```

Я пробовала различные вариации с параметрами окна, но не помогло.

Также я пробовала такой код:

```
SELECT 
    qu.created_at,
    sum(count(qu.id)) OVER (ORDER BY qu.created_at) as test_sum
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT ON (id)  created_at, 
        dao_id
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY id, created_at
) AS qu
GROUP BY 1
```

Но этот код выводит уникальное количество id на каждый день, отобрать строки на последний день каждого месяца у меня не получилось, хотя данные в этом случаю отображаются верно.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Минимальный пример в студию. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql/1035#1035 , особенно пункт 2.3.

Comment: По идее в подзапросе нужен order by, чтобы клиенты из первого месяца там и остались.

Answer (score 0):

Помог такой код:

```
select 
    month,
    sum(count(qu.id)) OVER (ORDER BY month) as num_used_feature_end_month
from (
    select 
        distinct on (id)  date_trunc('month', table.created_at) as month, 
        id
    from table
) AS qu
group by 1
```